# How to word sortArrayList

Tags: java

I divide the sentence into words received from the text I print the words and frequencies in the new text.

How do I arrange the words? I'd like to, but still lack basic as you learn.
Tell us the parts you need to fix in the source would really appreciate it.

```
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.util.Scanner;

class Item {

    protected String word;
    protected int frequency;

    public Item(String word, int frequency) {
        this.word = word;
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public Item() {
        this("", 0);
    }
}

class SortedArrayList {

    protected Item[] items;
    private int size = 0;
    private int maxSize = 10;

    public SortedArrayList() {
        items = new Item[maxSize];
    }

    public SortedArrayList(int max) {
        items = new Item[max];
        maxSize = max;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return size == maxSize;
    }

    public void insert(Item item) {
        if (isFull())
            resize();
        else if (isEmpty()) {
            items[0] = item;
            size++;
        } else if (items[size - 1].word == item.word) {
            for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0 && (items[i].word == item.word); i--) {
                items[i + 1] = items[i];
                items[i] = item;
            }
            size++;
        } else {
            items[size] = item;
            size++;
        }

    }

    public void addFrequency(Item item) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (items[i].word == item.word)
                items[i].frequency++;
    }

    public void resize() {
        Item[] resizeItems = new Item[2 * items.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            resizeItems[i] = items[i];
        }
        items = resizeItems;
        maxSize *= 2;
    }

    public void print(int i) {
        System.out.println(items[i].word + "\t" + items[i].frequency);
    }
}

public class WordFrequency {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        SortedArrayList[] list = new SortedArrayList[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            list[i] = new SortedArrayList();
        }
        String fileName = "sample.txt";
        Scanner inFile = null;
        inFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        String lineString;

        while (inFile.hasNextInt()) {
            lineString = inFile.nextLine();
            String[] array = lineString.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                Item it = new Item(array[i], 1);
                list[i].insert(it);
                list[i].addFrequency(it);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                list[i].print(i);
            }
        }
        inFile.close();

    }
}
```

---

If the content of the "sample.txt" is the same as the following

```
apple orange grape apple peach apple
```

The desired result

```
apple 3  
grape 1  
orange 1   
peach 1  
word:4 frequencies:6
```

Comment: For one, when you compare strings, you will want to use the .equals method, instead of ==. I.e you have items[i].word == item.word. That is comparing the reference and not the actual string value. You should use items[i].word.equals(item.word). Also, you currently have protected members in Item. I am assuming that both classes are in the same package.

Comment: @Derek_M You can make your comment easier to read if you surround code example with `\`` like `foo.equals(bar)` which was written as `\`foo.equals(bar)\``

Comment: Do you have to do it in this particular way that you have posted? There are so many other easier ways to solve this problem if you are allowed to use Java Collection Framework.

Comment: @mushfek0001   Yes, I must follow the above framework

Comment: @Derek_M 
Yes, same package
protected String word;
protected int frequency; Originally private members